# Filter Map Markers is Inconsistent

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to allow markers to be filtered on the map via a select box.

On each marker array there is a category object that has an array of categories that could match with what the user selects.

**Select Box**

```
<select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">
    <option value="">Please select category</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
     <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

**Filter Function**

```
filterMarkers = function (category) {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < marker.category.length; j++) {
        console.log(marker.category[j]);
          // If is same category or category not picked
          if (marker.category[j] == category || category.length === 0) {
              marker.setVisible(true);
          }
          // Categories don't match 
          else {
              marker.setVisible(false);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

But after it filters, it's not showing certain markers, such as the **green category**, and not all of the ones for the **red category** display either.

However, when I console.log the marker variable in the loop, it returns the proper matches, but it seems that the setVisible doesn't set it on all of the markers.

**JS Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/0v7yv6w8/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use MVCObject instead of looping.
[MVCObject](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MVCObject) is a super class of other classes (such as Map, Marker, Polygon, Polyline...).
Using the method of MVCObject, you can write filtering code very simply.

**MVCObject will fire "(key_name)_changed" event when the value is changed.**

For example:

```
var myObj = new google.maps.MVCObject();
myObj.set("choice", "category1");  // "choice_changed" event will be occurred.
myObj.set("choice", "category2");  // "choice_changed" event will be occurred.
```

And you can listen the event using addEventListener() or override the changed() method.

```
myObj.addListener("choice_changed", function() {
  var choice = myObj.get("choice");
  ...
});

or 

myObj.changed = function(key) {
  var choice = myObj.get(key);
  ...
};
```

As I described at the first, Marker class is inherited this MVCObject class, you can do same thing. Further more, Map class is also.

```
function createMarker(params) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(params);
  marker.changed = function(key) {
    if (key === 'choice') {
      var choice = marker.get('choice');
      marker.setVisible(choice === params.category); // true or false
    }
  };
  return marker;
}
var marker1 = createMarker({
  position: ...,
  category: "red"
});
var marker2 = createMarker({
  position: ...,
  category: "green"
});
```

MVCObject has a very useful method: `bindTo()`.
This method binds the value of the specified property.

For example:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(...);
map.bindTo('choice', marker1); // marker1.choice = map.choice
map.bindTo('choice', marker2); // marker2.choice = map.choice

map.set('choice', 'green');
console.log(marker1.get('choice'));  // 'green'
console.log(marker2.get('choice'));  // 'green'
```

In fact, using this mechanism, you just put the category value to the map.choice.
You don't need to looping all markers.

To more compact code, you can write the `bindTo()` method in the createMarker() function.

```
function createMarker(params) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker(params);

  params.map.bindTo('choice', marker);

  marker.changed = function(key) {
    if (key === 'choice') {
      var choice = marker.get('choice');
      marker.setVisible(choice === params.category); // true or false
    }
  };
  return marker;
}
```

Here is a demo code I wrote before.
There is a side bar right of the map.
You can change the category from "Nozomi Shinkansen", "Hikari Shinkansen", and "Kodama Shinkansen"

http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/map_example_sidebar2.html